# Number of pairs

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, integer

I am trying to write a code that takes

- m. a, a list of integers
- n. b, an integer and returns the number of pairs (m,n) with m,n in a such that |m-n|<=b.

So far, I've got this

```
from itertools import permutations

def close_pairs(l, d):
    for a,b in permutations(l, 2):
        if (a - b) <= d and (b - a) <= d:
            return len(a, b)

def main():
    # The close pairs are (1,2), (2,1), (2,5) and (5,2)
    # (1,5) and (5,1) don't count because their difference is 4 (which is >3)
    x = close_pairs( [1,2,5] , 3 )
    print( "close_pairs([1, 2, 5], 3) = " , close_pairs([1, 2, 5], 3) )

    # The close pairs are (1,2) and (2,1)
    y = close_pairs( [1, 2, 5] , 2 )
    print( "close_pairs([1, 2, 5], 2) = " , close_pairs([1, 2, 5], 2) )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The desired output should look like

```
>>> nearest_pairs([1,2,5],3) = 4,
```

where 4 is the number of close pairs according to the restrictions. However, I do not have this. Could anyone lead me to the right direction?